# Require extra information in Meteor account sign up

Tags: meteor

I'm working a Meteor app which uses `accounts-password`, and linking to other services wouldn't make sense. However, I would like to be able to require additional information, specifically their real name. From reading the docs, the data should be stored in `user.profile`. How can I require information at signup? My best guess is extend `accounts-password` and `accounts-ui`, but it seems like a common enough problem, so there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this currently that I know of. Extending Accounts-UI is a nightmare. I strongly suggest just doing it yourself, it's not very hard. Meteor provides the [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) function you could use for this, as well as other related simple to use functions in the [Passwords](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_passwords) documentation. The `createUser` function actually accepts an `options` object, which can specifically contain a `profile` object for the additional information you would like to add. Set up a template yourself with all the html form fields you want, make a submit event hook for it that calls either `Accounts.createUser` or a Meteor function that does some other stuff first. This method gives you styling flexibility also, which is a pain in the neck with the Accounts-UI package.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Accounts.createUser()` and something like:

```
Accounts.validateNewUser( function( user ) {
  return !!user.profile.name;
});
```

You'll probably want to make your own form for this - the `accounts-ui` package is great for prototyping, but when you need custom requirements like this it's easier to roll your own. See BenjaminRH's answer for the basics of creating a custom login form.